# Hyperlink on a whole section (ie6/7 fix)

Tags: css, html

I want to have a box that has an image and text in, and be clickable anywhere in the area for the hyperlink to work. Here's an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N7RRr/

As you can see, this works in your shiny new browser!

However, it doesn't work in IE 6/7, I've tried googling and haven't found the answer, so I'm hoping one of you know's a way (CSS only please)

Note: I'm aware that an `<a>` tag should not be the parent of `<section>`, but I could really do with this functionality without any javascript

Comment: Quote OP:  _"but I could really do with this functionality without any javascript"_ ~ Are you asking us or telling us?  And seriously, whomever is not using JavaScript, can't properly use any of the most popular websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/N7RRr/4/

Comment: Yes, it does. For some reason I never though about doing it like that. Exactly what I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Methinks you need to define section as a block level element... `section { display:block; }`.. since IE7/IE6 don't recognize it and parse it as inline.

EDIT: also specify the `a` as a block level and possibly feed it dimensions.

EDIT #2: You also absolutely need the html 5 shiv because otherwise the HTML 5 elements can't be created in older IEs.

Comment: That didn't work, I should probably be clearer:

The section itself gets the hyperlink, but children (img and text) dont get the hyperlink, so you were right in a way, I wasn't clear enough

Comment: I have the html5 shiv, my HTML5 elements are working (`<nav>` etc), section has its width, height etc set, I just want all of section to be a hyperlink

Comment: did you define `a` as block by giving it an id and assigning it the rule?

Comment: Ugh, stupid moment by me. Just been fixing as another user said, and realised it was working all along, the cursor just wasn't updating to "pointer" so i assumed the href wasn't there. Forced cursor:pointer and now its working exactly as I wanted it to.

Thanks for the help though, I have a feeling if it wasn't already working, you would have been right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the nodes for IE6-7? Section is HTML5, so you need to create that node.

Comment: Yeah I am, I've included the html5 shiv, and everything else is working (e.g my `<nav>`, `<header>` etc)

Comment: @user1538100, you realize that [HTML5shiv is JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv), right?

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware ie6/7 with JS turned off will see the site horribly, but I want to do this with CSS, if its possible, to learn

Answer (score 0):

I believe it won't matter how you style them, if you're not linking [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) (or some such piece of javascript)

This is because the older IE versions will simply ignore the `<section>` tag because they don't know about it. The workaround is to create one. After that, you can apply style to it. modernizer does this for you

Sorry that id does require javascript.

Comment: I'm referencing the html5 shiv, for HTML5, I just didn't want additional javascript for this specific functionality

Comment: in that case, I'm out of ideas at least until I get to an older computer so I can test some.